# FindControl in Custom ITemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, templates, itemplate

I have a custom UserControl which uses a simple ITemplate:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlExpander" CssClass="expander">
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkExpand" Text="More Options" NavigateUrl="#" CssClass="lnkExpand"/>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContent" CssClass="expanderContent" style="display: none">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcContent"/>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

The template is rendered with two simple properties:

```
public class Expander {
    private ITemplate _contentTemplate;
        public ITemplate ContentTemplate {
            get { return _contentTemplate; }
            set { _contentTemplate = value; }
    }
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
            if (ContentTemplate != null) {
                ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(plcContent);
            }
    }
```

Everything displays correctly, but I can't use FindControl within the template. I get a reference to my combobox from VS intellisense, but a compilation error that it's null whern I actually load the page.

To find the combobox in th the template, I'm using:

```
var cboFilterCriticality = AspNetUtils.FindControlRecursive(optionsExpander,"cboFilterCriticality") as DropDownList;
```

And the actual template looks like this on the page:

```
<l49:Expander runat="server" ID="optionsExpander">
    <ContentTemplate>
        ... other controls
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboFilterCriticality" runat="server" ValidationGroup="filterGrid" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Value" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</l49:Expander>
```

Comment: Good question.  Seems like it should work, but I get the same issue.  I can see the control if I  look at the controls collection in the watch window. You could always override the FindControl method.

Comment: That's what `FindControlRecursive` does, recursively iterates over the tree looking for my control, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by changing the UserControl which used an ITemplate. For some reason, it was calling `InstantiateIn` in `OnPreRender`, which is clearly way too late to render anything to be picked up by Page_Load in the page - see the [Page LifeCycle and UserControls (half way down)](http://blogs.thesitedoctor.co.uk/tim/2006/06/30/Complete+Lifecycle+Of+An+ASPNet+Page+And+Controls.aspx). I moved `InstantiateIn` to `OnInit` in the UserControl, and the problem solved itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.net's WebForm page:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlExpander" CssClass="expander">
    <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkExpand" Text="More Options" NavigateUrl="#" CssClass="lnkExpand"/>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlContent" CssClass="expanderContent" style="display: none">
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="plcContent"/>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

define the Expander class as following:

```
public class Expander { 
    public ITemplate ContentTemplate {get ;set;}
    public HtmlGenericControl ContentTemplateContainer{get;set;}
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e) {
        this.ContentTemplateContainer = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
        if (ContentTemplate != null) {
            ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
        }
        plcContent.Controls.Add(container);

    }
}
```

in OnInit of Page:

```
public override void OnInit(EventArgs e){
    base.OnInit(e);
    ViewState["ContentTemplateContainerID"] =  ContentTemplateContainer.ClientID;
}
```

and finally in Javascript :

```
var containerID = ViewState("ContentTemplateContainerID");
var elID = $get(containerID)[0].id;
var expander = $find(elID);
```